# How to fire one promise only after another promise resolved?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm new to JS and I don't understand the behaviour I see in the code snippet

```
const task1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => res('one'), 5000)
})

const task2 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => res('two'), 5000)
})

task1
.then((x) => {                    // first then
    return Promise.resolve(task2)
})
.then((res) => {console.log(res)}) // expect to log after 10 seconds, but logs after 5 seconds

async function test() {
  try {
    const res = await task1;
    const res2 = await task2;
    console.log(res2); // also logs after 5 seconds
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`error`);
  }
}

test();
```

My understanding is that the first ".then" only fires after task 1 resolves after 5 seconds,then task2 starts and resolves after another 5 seconds. However, the console logs after 5 seconds, not 10. Where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: Both setTimeouts start executing as soon as you create the `new Promise`s, so the timeouts are essentially running in parallel which is why both promises take ~5s to resolve.

Comment: Move `task2` into the callback or use `async`/`await`.

Comment: I see,  is there any way to modify the code to get my intended behaviour ?
I'm not allowed to move the decleration of task 1 or 2

Comment: Yes, move `task2` into the callback or use `async`/`await`. It's a simple modification.

Comment: Could elaborate a bit more on async/await ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises

Comment: @ModeratleyIced If you can't move the declarations of task 1 / 2, can you modify how they're declared? Eg: Make them functions that return promises which you invoke when you want the timer to begin?

Comment: If you can't change the order there's nothing you can do. You can't change the behavior of a promise if it's already resolved. It's like you are asking to change the execution of a code after it's finished and you have the output

Comment: @ModeratleyIced updated my answer to include a simpler array iteration

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By creating promises as `new Promise` you execute them immediately so they are independent and doesn't form any type of queue.

To solve that you should have your tasks as functions and call them in a queue (when a promise returned by a function is resolved, call the next function).

To run the next function you should call it inside `.then()` of the previous one.

You could also put your tasks into an array and call in a `for..of` loop.

To go fancy you could use an async generator function to convert your array of promise creating functions into an async generator and use `for await` to iterate your promises in a queue.

```html
<script type="module">

const task1 = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => res('one'), 1000)
})

const task2 = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => res('two'), 1000)
})

async function* queue(arr){
  for(const fn of arr){
    yield await fn();    
  }
}

// using then
await task1().then(result => (console.log(result), task2().then(result => console.log(result))));

// using await
console.log(await task1());
console.log(await task2());

// using an array
for (const task of [task1, task2]){
  console.log(await task());
}

// using async generator
for await(const result of queue([task1, task2])){
  console.log(result);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the second promise in the `then` solving block of the first (promises start executing as soon as they're created).  To fix your code so they sequentially execute as promises:

```js
const promiseTime = 500;
const start = performance.timeOrigin + performance.now();
const task = new Promise((res, rej) => {setTimeout(() => res('one'), promiseTime);});

task
  .then((x)=>{
    console.log(`${x} ${(performance.timeOrigin + performance.now())-start}`);
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {setTimeout(() => res('two'), promiseTime);});
  })
  .then((x)=>{
    console.log(`${x} ${(performance.timeOrigin + performance.now())-start}`);
  });

//Console output example (F12 to see, or run the snippet):
//  one 516.677001953125
//  two 1033.35400390625
```

If you want to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await) with promises:

```js
const promiseTime = 500;
const start = performance.timeOrigin + performance.now();

const res1 = await new Promise((res, rej) => {setTimeout(() => res('one'), promiseTime);});
//Will log as soon as promise 1 is complete
console.log(`${res1} ${(performance.timeOrigin + performance.now())-start}`);

const res2 = await new Promise((res, rej) => {setTimeout(() => res('two'), promiseTime);});
//Will log as soon as promise 2 is complete:
console.log(`${res2} ${(performance.timeOrigin + performance.now())-start}`);

//Console output example (F12 to see):
//  one 500.010009765625
//  two 1083.35498046875
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I find that it works, but I dont have the option of changing where th promises are created.  Is there a workaround, or is my expected behaviour impossible ?

Comment: @ModeratleyIced A promise is fired when it's created. The expected behavior is impossible. The best you can do is to add a logic inside the promise constructor callback to allow starting the promise later.